# Htaccess Rewrite Guidance

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

Please help me set up a rewrite on my `.htaccess` file. Here is an example URL that I would like to have re-written:

`www.domain.com/img/another-folder/500x700.jpg?w=500&h=700`

You can see I link directly to a `.jpg` file and store the dimensions into variables `w` and `h`. I want to remove everything entirely after `www.domain.com` and just keep the variables I stored, so it looks like:

`www.domain.com/500/700`

What is the best way of doing this?

All help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The best way is to implement a RewriteRule for that. Either in a `.htaccess` style file, or, preferably in the http servers host configuration. I suggest you start by reading the documentation of the tool you want to use: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html It is of excellent quality and comes with great examples.

Comment: Thanks @arkascha. I kind of already knew I needed a RewriteRule though. That's what I'm asking for assistance about. While I continue reading these very confusing docs, anyone with an answer would be super helpful!

Comment: Please understand that SO is _not_ a free coding service. You are expected to learn about the topic yourself, make an own attempt and present what you have so far when asking a question. Anyway, take a look below, I quick typed a simple solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a direct implementation of what you ask:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ /img/another-folder/500x700.jpg?w=$1&h=$2 [END]
```

That rule will work in dynamic configuration files *and* in the real http servers host configuration.

You obviously will need the rewriting module to be enabled. And, if you use a `.htaccess` style file, then its interpretation hs to be enabled first too.

If you are using a really old version of the apache http server then you might need to replace the `END` flag with the `L` flag. Have a try with that if you receive a http status 500 upon a request (internal server error).

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).